# Конфигурация "dev mode"

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

Использую Spring Boot. Подкажите как "сказать" приложению для запуска в "dev" или "prodaction" mode. Есть причина так пуступить - в dev нужно опустить процесс авторизации пользователей.
Предпологаю что нужен какой-либо внешний конфигурационный файл, runtime параметр или может есть что-то специфицеское для Spring Boot? Подскажите самый оптимальный вариант и может есть где подсмотреть решение.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но осталось понятным акак использовать разные конфугурационные файлы, но как поменять поведение классов в зависимости от environment?

Answer (score 0):

Как отмечают [здесь](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles), вы можете через аннотацию `@Profile` активировать конфигурации в зависимости от активного профиля.

Выдержка из JavaDoc:

> If a @Configuration class is marked with @Profile, all of the @Bean methods and @Import annotations associated with that class will be bypassed unless one or more of the specified profiles are active.

Соответственно, вам нужно указать профиль в этой аннотации и проинициализировать бины специфическим для данного профиля образом.